# Wrap superglobals in a class?

Tags: php, oop, superglobals

Should I just call them by their name `$_GET, $_POST, $_SESSION //etc`, or should I wrap them in a class? For example for the POST superglobal, so that it returns false if a certain array index is not set?

Let's say I have a Validator class. So I have to pass through every field like so `$_POST['name']` but if it's not set it will return an undefined index error. But if it would return false instead that wouldn't happen.

**Is there any preferred way or best practice to use superglobals?**

Comment: That's a common practice among php frameworks, you could look into their source code for inspiration and examples

Comment: "best practice" is a loathsome meaningless term

Comment: It's worth thinking about testing: it's very hard to do testing with superglobals spread about your code. If you have an object that contains those values, that can be populated by the superglobals in the normal course of events and by other methods in testing.

Comment: So it would be kind of a good idea to let my requestHandler take care of the superglobals (wrapping them)?

Comment: PHP allows you to create OOP code, but that does not mean you have to turn everything into OOP. One of PHP's strengths is giving you the flexibility to choose, so returning false/null vs testing before each use boils down to your preference IMO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might create an Input class that takes care of that. Just a stub:

```
class Input
{
   private $_post;
   private $_get;
   private $_session;
   private $_server;

   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->_post = $_POST;
      $this->_get = $_GET;
      // and so on
   }

   public function post($key = null, $default = null)
   {
       return $this->checkGlobal($this->_post, $key, $default);
   }

   public function get($key = null, $default = null)
   {
       return $this->checkGlobal($this->_get, $key, $default);
   }

   // other accessors

   private function checkGlobal($global, $key = null, $default = null)
   {
     if ($key) {
       if (isset($global[$key]) {
         return $global[$key];
       } else {
         return $default ?: null;
       }
     }
     return $global;
   }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
$input = new Input();
print_r($input->post()); // return all $_POST array
echo $input->post('key'); // return $_POST['key'] if is set, null otherwise
echo $input->post('key', 'default'); // return 'default' if key is not set
```

Of course you need to expand this further, but that's the idea.

Edit:

if you feel better, you can make this part of your request handler:

```
namespace App;

use App\Input;

class Request
{
   private $input;

   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->input = new App\Input();
   }

   public function post($key = null)
   {
      return $this->input->post($key);
   }
}
```

Comment: This would be called a helper class, right? Not a library. Just curious to know where to store the file in my MVC folder structure.

Comment: Why wouldn't that be a library? I called it Input for simplicity's sake, but if you want to make it part of the request handler (seems right), the logic remains the same.

Comment: Would Call this Utility. Helper depends on other Objects.

Comment: You decoupled it, but couldn't I just merge this entire input class with the request handler class as it's a part of that?

Comment: Well, of course. That was just an indication and a quickly coded example ;)

Answer (score 0):

You Could have an Application Object, and Assign Superglobals to them

```
class Request {
    public static function GetUrlParameter($key, $default = '') {
        return isset ($_GET[$key]) ? $_GET[$key] : $default;
    }
}

$app = new Application();
$app->Page = Request::GetUrlParameter('page', 'home');
$app->PostBacks = $_POST;
$app->Render();
```

Sure PostBacks ist quick and dirty. You want to have a Module Object for each Module/Formular, where you can assign your PostBacks (i. e. Username, Password) like Page to the Application Object.

Edited. Added part of a Request Class i have written for my needs, thanks for Dave's Comment.

Upvoted Question. I am also interested in alternative Solutions.

Comment: I believe this would still emit a warning. Only wrapping it within an isset or empty would work.